# The behavioral voltage source in Ltspice, is there a physical circuit that we can use?

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to make a physical circuit of the circuit shown below:

[image: Circuit]

All the components can be found easily like the resistors, capacitors, bjt except the behavioral voltage source. So can anyone tell me how to use that in the real physical circuit, is there a device that I can buy or make a separate subcircuit to implement the same thing that behavioral voltage source does?

Here V(a) is a DC voltage source going from 0 to 0.1 with 0.01 step and V(b) is the AC voltage source, a sine wave with 3V amplitude and 10k frequency.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not without knowing what V(a) and V(b) are. But there are analog multipliers which may help.

Comment: sorry about that, I just added it, and thank you for the comment.

Comment: They can be rather expensive, but an [arbitrary waveform generator](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=arbitrary+waveform+generator&t=opera&ia=web) might work - just set the desired output characteristics.

Comment: If you're into experimentation, you could also try a current generator modulated by the first voltage, into a voltage controlled resistor (e.g. JFET).

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that you have made an ac source with variable amplitude.

I would suggest that you use whatever kind of sine oscillator you like, followed by a variable gain amplifier.

You could even try an oscillator with its output connected to a potentiometer, with the potentiometer wiper connected to a unity-gain buffer.

Answer (score 2):

First off, a note that this is more general of an answer than you require; you seem to be simply stepping the amplitude of a sine wave, which is much easier than this. But for the purposes of education, and because Gilbert cells are neat:

---

If you can generate V1 and V2, there *is* a method of multiplying them: Use an analog multiplier. These are constructed around a nonlinear multiplying element called a Gilbert cell, which uses multiple long-tailed pairs connected together to produce a reasonably accurate output proportional to the product of its inputs. They're not cheap, as they're rarely used and require precise matching of the transistors and biasing circuitry to work correctly (you definitely can't make one out of discrete transistors), but some, like the AD633, can be reasonably affordable.

Analog multipliers generally have an output voltage equal to \$\frac{V_{1}V_{2}}{V_{3}}\$, for input voltages \$V_1\$, \$V_2\$, and \$V_3\$. The reason for this is that the output must also be a voltage, and the product of two voltages is a squared voltage, not a voltage. You have to divide by a third voltage in order to get an output with the correct dimension. This is a handy feature, anyway, as it lets you scale down the output to reasonable levels.

Comment: His "carrier" frequency is so low, he can probably get away with some of the legacy parts such as the [MC1496](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc1496-d.pdf) or [SA612A](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SA612A.pdf).  Both are still in production.